# Вывод сообщений консоли в Tmemo на кириллице

Tags: delphi, кодировка, кириллица

В некоторой тулзе заюзал процедурку - **ExecConsoleApp** [[её source]](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/base/createprocess_console.html)
Но дело в том, что она выдаёт кракозябры, вместо кириллицы при выводе результатов работы команды в TMemo.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

У вас кодовая страница консоли 866, да? Тогда прогоняем через [OEMToAnsi](http://superadm.net/index.php?name=pages&op=view&id=184)
ЗЫ [Про кракозябры](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQiJn.png)